# Socket.io emit method is blocked by previous emit method?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I am trying to create a chat App and learning how to use Socket.io. Everything was fine until now. I faced some weird behaviour from socket.emit method. I placed two socket.emit() methods one by one like this:

```
      socket.emit("LEAVE_GROUP_ROOM", groupId , authUser)
      socket.emit("USER_IS_OFFLINE", authUser, authUserFriends)
```

My problem here is that only the first emit is completed and reaches the server. Second one seems like not even executed. If i change the order of emit methods then then again the first one only works and second not. Individually, these methods work fine. Can you explain to me why its not working porperly? It seems like first emit block second one